# Wordpress -> Yoast SEO settings -> error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'prevOffset')

Tags: wordpress, hebrew, yoast

I simply wanted to go over the settings of Yoast SEO on my site, and got to this error message:

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ‘prevOffset’)

[image]

This error appears on every page of the Yoast settings.

I saw some information about this issue and the relation to a problem with translations, but didn’t understand it and how to resolve it in my case.

I should mention that my site is in Hebrew.

So why is this happening now and how do I resolve it?

Thanks.

Comment: What did the support team tell you?

Comment: nothing yet. I've found something about this error, but didn't understand what they offered there for resolution. so I opened a topic of my own about this, and didn't get a reply yet. @Kaddath

Answer (score 0):

This plugin solved it for me: [force update translations](https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-update-translations/)